# Search on multiple keywords in a single search text field (RAILS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search

I'm fairly new and playing around with searching databases in Rails. I have a model and database that has a list of names under the 'name' attribute. I want to be able to enter search keywords into a single search field and this input can be one word or two words or more, depending on how specific a result the user wants.

Right now, I'm using something ugly as shown below, which will do a maximum of 3 search terms. Is there a way to make this dynamic for 'search_length' keywords? The find method is clearly repetitive, but I'm not sure how to automate it and haven't found any useful suggestions elsewhere online.

```
def self.search(search)

  if search
    search_length = search.split.length
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ? AND name LIKE ? AND name LIKE ?', 
    "%#{search.split[0]}%", "%#{search.split[1]}%", 
    "%#{search.split[search_length1]}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

Other than this, loving Rails so far.

Thanks Much,
Lev

Answer (score 7):

The code from Łukasz Śliwa works great if you close the name variable with the other % sign.

The complete code from above working for me. Great post.

```
def self.search(search)

  if search
    search_length = search.split.length
    find(:all, :conditions => [(['name LIKE ?'] * search_length).join(' AND ')] + search.split.map { |name| "%#{name}%" })
  else
    find(:all)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this:

```
find(:all, :conditions => [(['name LIKE ?'] * search_length).join(' AND ')] + search.split.map { |name| "%#{name}" })
```

I looks strange but, first generate search_length times string 'name LIKE ?':

```
 ['name LIKE ?'] * search_length
```

then you have array with some keys, so let's join all of them with ' AND ':

```
 ["name LIKE ? ", "name LIKE ? ", "name LIKE ? "].join(' AND ')
```

and finally merge with another array.

Comment: Thanks I'll play around with that.

Comment: I think I have the first part where we create the right number of 'name like ?' joins. The last part is still fishy where I have to specify the keywords that match the conditions. Should I be passing an array there?

Comment: This code seems to work for 1 keyword, but breaks down for more. If entering two search terms, you get a "wrong number of bind variables" error.

Answer (score 0):

```
formatted_columns = format_column_names(Sub.column_names)
where(formatted_columns.map {|cn| "#{cn} like ?" }.join("or "), *(["%#{search}%"] * formatted_columns.size))
```

this takes care of all columns as well as the correct amount of fields