# Rails 4 search separate keywords with wrong number of bind variables (1 for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have this tentative search function, however, it is limited to search one chunk of keyword only.

```
  def self.search(search)
    search_condition = "%" + search + "%"
    active.where("lower(title) LIKE ?", search_condition.downcase)
  end
```

E.g. I have this title: "Peter Paul Mary"

If I search "peter Mary", it doesn't show.

I found this code useful [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337381/search-on-multiple-keywords-in-a-single-search-text-field-rails):

```
def self.search(search)

if search
    search_length = search.split.length
    find(:all, :conditions => [(['name LIKE ?'] * search_length).join(' AND ')] + search.split.map { |name| "%#{name}%" })
  else
    find(:all)
  end

end
```

Unfortunately, it's in older rails.

So, how do I translate this into rails 4?

---

### Update:

I've changed to something like this:

```
  def self.search(str)
    search   = str.split.map{|w| "(lower(title) LIKE ? )"}.join(" OR ")
    values = str.split.map{|w| "%#{w.downcase}%"}.map(&:inspect).join(', ')
    .where("#{search}", values)
  end
```

But it raises this error:

```
ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid (wrong number of bind variables (1 for 2) in: (lower(title) LIKE ? ) OR (lower(title) LIKE ? )):
```

**Please advise.**

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to be using Postgres with your app, then you can easily take advantage of PG's Full Text Search capabilities using the [pg_search gem](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search).

You can also plug into frameworks like Solr or ElasticSearch to give you this functionality, but they will increase you development effort.

PG and MySQL both also have pattern matching functions that would allow you to search based on a regex string from the search values.